# Get screen reader to read IT as I T in SharePoint

Tags: html

I want screen readers to read the word IT on my page as I T (as in Information Technology) - not the word `it`.  I do not want to show a space on the screen though as it just does not look right.  How can I code this to get a screen reader to read it as though there were a space between I and T?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<p>The word <acronym>IT</acronym></p>
<style>
  acronym {speak : spell-out;}
</style>
```

---

or this*

```
<p>The word <abbr class="spell">IT</abbr></p>
<style>
  abbr.spell {speak : spell-out;}
</style>
```

*) acronym tag is removed from HTML5 specification.

Answer (score 1):

Put the letters "I T" in a SPAN tag and define this with negative letter spacing in CSS http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp

Then the space will not be seen in the browser but read correctly by screen readers

ie

```
<span class="nospace">I T</span>
```

and then CSS

```
span.nospace { letter-spacing: -1px }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is just a visual hack and any time the CSS does not apply, the space will appear. For example: in search engine listings.

Comment: @Quentin Well, one could do the opposite, wrap the letters IT in a span class and then add a space with javascript depending on media...

Answer (score 1):

While this will vary between different screenreaders, I think you will find that, for most, the solution is to *type in capital letters*.

My screenreader (VoiceOver) pronounces each letter in both IT and I T for the title of this question.

Comment: I have it typed in capitals but the screenreader I used to test read it as a word "it". I cannot rely on everyone using a decent screenreader :)